# 3 Squares Matchsticks

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

[image]

How can you move 3 matchsticks in order to make the above figure balance symmetrically?

Note: Cutting through the center of gravity of the new figure must make 2 equal halves or sets (i.e. we seek reflectional symmetry of the figure).

Comment: What kind of symmetry are we aiming for? Left/right? Top/bottom? Rotational? EDIT: Also, do the heads of the matches count as part of the symmetry?

Comment: @LeafyGreens  360degrees-Yes

Comment: The match heads have to be symmetrical?

Comment: Need to balance

Comment: Why are people hating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should work.

> [image: ans] 
>  This has 180 degree rotation symmetry. Any line drawn through the center would create two congruent halves, with matchstick heads taken into account.

### [old answer]

Like this? Seems pretty symmetrical to me.

> [image]

Comment: Gah, you beat me while I was trying to format my post DX

Comment: If by symmetrical the OP means "mirrored", then no, it's not (he said the match heads count, although the statement was pretty vague about it).

Comment: Given what OP said, I now believe the real problem is constructing a figure such that any line drawn through the center divides it into congruent halves i.e. it should have 180 degree rotational symmetry. I update my answer.

Comment: The snail figure is correct!

Answer (score 2):

Before:

> ```
>        _ 
>      _|_|_
>     |_| |_|
> ```

After:

> ```
>      _ _  
>     |_|_|  
>     |_|_|
> ```

Comment: The "window"  figure will tilt like the plus sigh

Comment: @TSLF I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "tilt"?

Comment: I cant see the heads but mostly that figure isn't symmetrically balanced. Cutting through  c,g. gives equal rotational or mirrored halves

Comment: You absolutely need to specify that the heads count.

Comment: "center of gravity" includes everything in this lateral thinking-puzzle